# Calculating the resistor needed for a simple LED and battery circuit

Tags: resistance, ohms-law

I'm having trouble learning the most basic circuit math!

I've a 3V battery pack, two AAA, a standard plastic LED and a pack of resistors and I need to work out which resistor I need.

I'm assuming the voltage drop of the LED is 2.0V; the datasheet only states a "forward voltage" of 2.0-2.4V and some wavelengths and lumens.

The problem I have is that the math `drop / current` requires a value for current, but I don't know that yet. In the YouTube tutorials I've seen, `I` just gets written in as if its value was magically known (0.02A).

My understanding is that the current is "drawn" by the loads on the circuit, which include the LED and maybe the resistor itself.

So my confusion is that there's a circular dependency, or chicken-egg situation, I need to build the circuit to measure the current it draws in order to arrive at `R` and build the circuit.

What's going on? Perhaps the datasheet or testing and measuring components in isolation breaks this deadlock? Perhaps I'm just tired.

Comment: The LEDs you bought in the [Sparkfun LED assortment pack](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12062) are just whatever random parts they had laying around.  Assume 20 milliamperes as a safe upper limit to figure out the lowest resistor value you can use.  In reality, you'll use something larger because the maximum safe current is pretty dang bright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the resistor will determine the brightness of the LED. The resistor limits the current drawn by the LED, preventing it from drawing too much current, and "popping". Put in a 10k resistor, see how bright it is, and do the math with that. Vary the resistor up and down, and do the math with each. This will give you a feel for what current values correspond to what brightness levels.

Comment: Unless of course the OP tries a 1 ohm resistor next...

Comment: Thank you. This is interesting because it implies that the resistor is the very thing that changes `I` but `I` is needed to determine `R`, but actually what I'm doing is choosing `I` by varying `R` and my choice for `R` is based on how safely bright I want my LED. It also just made me consider that perhaps the LED will draw enough current to kill itself, so the LED doesn't have a preset/natural value `I`. Maybe.

Comment: You are correct. There is a range of current values that will light the LED, which correspond to brightness levels. Also, too small a resistor, and, POP! it will draw too much current and destroy itself. Too large a resistor, and it won't light at all. If this answered your question, please check the answered button. I could use the reputation. Thanks!

Comment: I like all the responses, they've all helped, thank you. I'm going to award the answer to this one as its re-framed the situation and my mental model.

Comment: @LukePuplett: It is important to remember that LEDs can operate over a wide range of current, as long as you keep below their Absolute Maximum rating.  I had some green LEDs that I had to run at less than 1 mA to get them dim enough for my liking.

Answer (score 1):

You said that the datasheet states a range of forward voltage. The same line in the datasheet should also tell you the amount of current that was passing through the LED when they made the voltage measurement. It may be called \$I_F\$, the forward current, and that is the value your need to calculate the necessary resistor value.

Comment: Thank you Elliot. The more I keep reading and watching, and with your answer, the more I'm coming to the conclusion that the datasheet is incomplete and therefore I'm left in chasing my tail. http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LED/COM-12062.jpg

Comment: That isn't really a datasheet at all. Sparkfun usually does a better job. If you want to go ahead and use the LEDs, I would **guess** that a current of about 20mA would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Given the limited data, we just have to make a few assumptions.  Almost all standard 5mm LEDs can take 20mA (0.02A), so let's pick that.

The supply is 3V.  The LED drops 2V.  That leaves 1V across the resistor.  Use the standard Ohms law equation V/I = R, gives 1/0.02 = 50 ohms.  If you haven't got a 50 ohm resistor, then 47 ohm is a common value, and close enough.

If the LED actually takes 2.4V, it won't be as bright as expected.  Some trial-and-error may be needed.  But LEDs will light at currents well below 20mA.